# load() inserts the entire page instead of a fragment when using variable

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to load a fragment of a page, more exactly `#index-section`, but if I use a variable for the page's URL, it loads the entire page.

```
nextPage = 2;
nextURL = '/page/' + nextPage;
console.log(nextURL); // returns /page/2
$('#index-section').load(nextURL + '#index-section'); // loads entire page
```

If I use the URL directly, with no variable, it works great

```
$('#index-section').load('/page/2 #index-section');
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a space between the url and the selector

```
$('#index-section').load(nextURL + ' #index-section');
//                                  ^
```

Comment: Wow that was so easy and it drove me crazy.